# Bootstrap container-fluid isn't the whole width of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a site and I'm starting with the mobile stylesheet first.
But the container-fluid's width isn't the same as the window's width.

What I tried to do to fix this was:

```
 .container-fluid{
      width: 105%
 }
```

The problem now is that when I make the window a little smaller, it's still not enough, but when I make the window a little bit bigger, it's TOO MUCH, when I do that a scroll bar appears at the bottom.

100% doesn't work since I already said that it's not the full width of the window.

Here's the entire body from the HTML file:

```
<body>
<!-- Introduction -->

<div id="introduction" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <header>
            <h1> Mosescu Bogdan Gabriel </h1>
            <img id="profilepic" src="profilepic.png" />
            <h2> Web Designer | Motion Graphics Artist </h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //Introduction// -->

<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 id="about-title"> Who I am </h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the CSS file:

```
/*Introduction CSS */
#introduction{
background-color: #542437;
color: white;
margin-top: -21px;
}
#introduction header{
text-align: center;
}
#introduction header h1{
font-family: montserrat;
font-weight: bold;
}
#introduction header h2{
font-family: montserrat;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1em;
}
#profilepic{
border-radius: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
/* //Introduction CSS// */


/* About CSS */
#about{
background-color: #f2f2f2;
color: #1a1a1a;
text-align: center;
margin-top: -24px;
}
#about-title{
font-family: montserrat;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 2.25em;
border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/599/?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Bootstrap containers have padding. You have to remove the padding.

Comment: Removing the padding shows no changes at all :/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Bootstrap containers are padded.

```
 .container-fluid {
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto
 }
```

You need to remove the padding.

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto
 }
```

Edit: This is a bare bones example. If you copy this and paste into a new .html document you'll see no padding on the container. If you then remove the `container-fluid` override you'll see padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- put your override styles here - AFTER you include Bootstrap -->
        <link href="style-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <style>
        /* override Bootstrap's container */
        .container-fluid {
            padding-right:0;
            padding-left:0;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-left:auto
         }
    </style>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
            This text hits the left side of the viewport.
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Edited HTML example to include new css link

### Edit: Bootstrap 4

@Dagrooms commented: "The best way to do this in Bootstrap 4 is to add `px-0` to your `container-fluid` div."

This will remove the padding from the left and right of the container, so that it will touch the sides of the browser viewport.

```html
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    This text hits the left side of the viewport.
</div>
```

Comment: Then my guess is that you have some padding elsewhere that's interfering.

Comment: What you sent fills the width of my browser. My assumption is that you must have something else somewhere that's still interfering.

Comment: Include your entire page, but by updating your original question; don't keep posting things as answers.

Comment: What's going on inside `style-mobile.css`? You said this is Bootstrap but I don't see a `bootstrap.css` file.

Comment: I included it in the HTML file, but I thought it's pretty irrelevant to show it.

Comment: Are you including it before or after `style-mobile.css`? You need to include it *before* and then you can override the the `.container-fluid` class as I showed you.

Comment: Glad that fixed it. Also, put your JavaScript files at the bottom of your pages to prevent render blocking. :)

Comment: The best way to do this in Bootstrap 4 is to add "px-0" to your "container-fluid" div like so:

`<div class="container-fluid px-0">...</div>`

This makes the padding `p` on x-direction `x` (which is left and right) zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, wrap all the content inside `container-fluid` with a bootstrap `row` class. It should work, thanks.

```
<div id="introduction" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <header>
      <h1> Mosescu Bogdan Gabriel </h1>
      <img id="profilepic" src="profilepic.png" />
      <h2> Web Designer | Motion Graphics Artist </h2>
    </header>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="about-title"> Who I am </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, I completely copied everything in the jsfiddle link and replaced it with mine. It is still the same exact thing. Can it have something to do with the fact that I scaled down my browser to simulate a phone?

Comment: This worked just perfect. After seeing this code I realized where I had screwed-up. I took off the column classes and everything fell into place. This is my working bit:

<pre> <code><div id="home-page-slider" class="container-fluid home-page-slider">
  <div class="row">
      <img src='source' />
  </div>
</div></pre> </code>

Answer (score 1):

If you just change .container-fluid that won't work because the row and col inside the container all get their own corrections. Try adding full-width to your container-fluid and then adding this:

```css
.full-width { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }
.full-width .row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }
.full-width .col-md-12 { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0"> 

  <div class="row m-auto">

    your content here

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of searching and trying out what did it for me in the end was a "w-100" in the "col-xs-12" div tag.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 w-100">
      My content that did not span 100% now with w-100 it does
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div className="container-fluid p-0 m-0 row justify-content-center" >`

If you use bootstrap, you can use `p-0` and `m-0` and they will set the 15px padding from `.container-fluid` and -15px margin from `.row` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many ways to do this. in Bootstrap 4, all you have to do is wrap the Container in a Div with Class=Row

```
<div class="Row">
   <header class="container-fluid">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-secondary">
      <h1 class="navbar-brand">Try this out</h1>
     </nav>    
   <header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I could get to work, after trying most of these answers.

css:

```
#mydiv {
  margin: 0 -9999rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
  background-color:#2A2A52
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <p>YOUR CONTENT HERE</p>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

note: I needed to specify px-0 on the container and wrap the row in a separate div in order for the text to line up horizontally with additional text on the page that was part of a typical container-fluid div.

Answer (score -1):

If none of this works try:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

to remove the padding/margin that might be overlapping on your code. It worked for me, since adding a row wrapping the container-fluid created a horizontal scroll on my page.